# How to associate user with progress in lessons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-activerecord, model-associations

Apologies, I'm very new to Rails, Devise, and model-associations.

I have a `User` model generated with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and a `Lesson` model. Each lesson has multiple parts. I'd like to keep track of which parts in a given lesson a user has completed.

So in terms of model-associations I think I need this:

```
User
    has_many :progressions

Progression 
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :lesson
    has_many :parts

Lesson
    has_many :parts

Part
    belongs_to :lesson
```

Does this seem like the right way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine. It would be easier to access parts through lessons for progresssions.

```
Progression
  has_one :lesson
  has_many :parts, through: :lesson
```